# Facing an issue while converting invalid date string to valid date string in SQL11g getting error ORA-01858

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am facing an issue when I was converting invalid date format to valid date format using the TO_DATE function, Here I explained my problem in the easiest way possible but in reality, the data is huge and having this problem. If you can provide me with a solution to this problem then it will be much helpful.
I tried this ->

```
Select TO_DATE('TWENTY-THREE,JANUARY,1998' , 'FMDDSP,MONTH,YYYY') From DUAL;
```

As I am having input date string as - DD in spelled format as you can see i.e. twenty-three, twenty-four. I want to convert that into valid date format to dd-mon-yy So that I can store them into the database.
Right now I am getting Error  -
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.
I am using oracle 11g (SQL*plus)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, afaik TO_DATE does not support the conversion from format sp or spth. That only works the other way round, with TO_CHAR. So you are left here with the only option of writing your own conversion function in PL/SQL. or Java.